# Remove old content, load in new content, animate new content with JQuery

Tags: jquery, load, jquery-animate, hide, show

I apologize that I am very much a novice with javascript. I have sort of picked up aspects of JQuery to augment my website designs but I never properly learned the fundamentals or syntax.

Here is what I want to do: When a user clicks on a a link in the list #nav the div #content will be animated up off the top of the screen by the height of #content. Then #content will be hidden. Then #content will be replaced by new content loaded in from the page that is linked to with the link the user clicked on in #nav. #content needs to remain hidden then move below the screen by the height of the viewport. Then #content will be made visible and animated back to its original location. Below is the code I mocked up but it isn't working properly.

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

    var oldHeight = $('#content').css("height");

    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    $('#content').animate({
        top: "-" + oldHeight
    }, 'slow');

    $('#content').hide();

    $('#content').load(toLoad);

    $('#content').animate({
        top: viewportHeight + "px"
    });

    $('#content').show();

    $('#content').animate({
        top: "0px"
    }, 'slow');

    return false;

});

});
```

Comment: Explain what is not working, if possible set up a JSFiddle with your current solution, as your explanation of what you need seems complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking it to perform everything after your `load()` only when it loads something ...

`load()` is async and you can see the full signature of the method in [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/load/), where it says that you can append a `function` that will fire when the load as completed.

from your example just put everything after your `load()` inside that method...

the final result should look like:

```
var clickedAnchors = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function() {

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';        
        var oldHeight = $('#content').css("height");        
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#content').animate({
            top: "-" + oldHeight
        }, 'slow', function() {

          $('#content').hide();        
          $('#content').load(toLoad, function() {


            $('#content').animate({
               top: viewportHeight + "px"
            });

            $('#content').show();        
            $('#content').animate({
                top: "0px"
            }, 'slow');

          }); // close load

        }); // close animate

        return false;

    }); // close selector
}); // close document.ready
```

Remember that one of the nicer features of jQuery is cascading, so your code could actually look like this:

```
var clickedAnchors = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function() {

      var currentId = $(this).attr('id');

      if($.inArray(currentId, clickedAnchors) < 0) {
        // this anchor was not yet clicked

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content',        
            oldHeight = $('#content').css("height"),        
            viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        $('#content').animate({ top: "-" + oldHeight }, 'slow', function() {

            // after animated is completed
            $('#content')
                .hide()
                .load(toLoad, function() {    

                    $(this).animate( { top: viewportHeight + "px" }, function() {

                        // after animation has completed
                        $(this)
                           .show()
                           .animate({ top: "0px" }, 'slow');

                    });
                });
        });

        // remove this anchor from being clicked again,
        // so let's add it's id into the array
        clickedAnchors.push(currentId);
      }

      return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: I do have a follow up question. How would I set this up to not run if a user clicks the link to load the content that is already displayed? For instance if a user clicks the link for "page" it will run the function, do all the animation and display the new content. But if the user clicks the link for "page" a second time it will run the animation again even though the content for "page" is already displayed.

Comment: so you want to run only once... then you simply need to **detach** the click even from that anchor tag (link)... I'll update the code imagining that each anchor has an unique `id`.

Comment: The updated code you provided is working well, but I want to be able to run the function more than once, just not load the same content twice in a row. Sorry, I wasn't clear about what I needed the code to do.

If this helps make it more clear, what I am building is a portfolio page where the user can pull up different projects by clicking on items in the nav. I want the user to be able to load "project 1", then load "project 2", then load "project 1" again if they wish. I just don't want to reload "project 1" if that is already the content loaded on the page.

Comment: I figured it out. Added .addClass('active') and .siblings().removeClass('active') and then housed the whole thing in an if statement that checks if it has the class 'active'

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the callback function for your animations so things fire in-order:

```
$(function() {

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

        //notice I used commas to separate the variable declarations, and I cached the `#content` selection since it will be used several times
        var toLoad         = $(this).attr('href') + ' #content',
            oldHeight      = $('#content').css("height"),
            viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
            $content       = $('#content');

        //animate the element out-of-view
        $content.animate({
            top : "-" + oldHeight
        }, 'slow', function () {

            //once the animation is complete, load the new data via AJAX
            $content.load(toLoad, function () {

                //once the AJAX request is complete, then animate the element back into view
                $content.animate({
                    top : "0px"
                }, 'slow');
            });
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

When you do this:

```
    $('#content').animate({
        top: "-" + oldHeight
    }, 'slow');

    $('#content').hide();
```

You are saying to take like 750ms to animate the element out-of-view, but you are instantly saying, "give the element `display : none`", so the element is being hid with `.hide()` before the `.animate()` call finishes. This is why we use callbacks.

Also, if you are going to run two or more functions on a jQuery object then you should chain the function calls rather than re-selecting the element(s):

```
    $('#content').animate({
        top: "-" + oldHeight
    }, 'slow').css({ color : '#fff' });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond!